# DOM Tree reduce using RAMDA

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I want to walk a DOM tree in the browser collecting DOM nodes that are "leaves", containing no DOM children, only text nodes.

I'm imagining there's a way to do this with reduce, but it's not obvious to me how to ... Recursively reduce on a tree like structure.

I've built a bunch of usable components...

```
let nodeFromJQuery = R.invoker(1,'get')(0);
let nodeFromAny = R.ifElse(R.isArrayLike,nodeFromJQuery,R.identity);
let nodeType = R.pipe(nodeFromAny,R.prop('nodeType'));
let children = R.pipe(nodeFromAny,R.prop('childNodes'));
let textNodeType = R.equals(3);
let domNodeType = R.equals(1);

let domNodes = R.map(isDomNode);
let textNodes = R.map(isTextNode);

let isTextNode = R.pipe(nodeType, textNodeType);
let isDomNode = R.pipe(nodeType,domNodeType);
let domChildren = R.pipe(children,R.filter(isDomNode));

isLeaf = R.pipe(domChildren, R.isEmpty);

getNodes = R.filter(R.not(isLeaf));
getLeaves = R.filter(isLeaf)
```

but I don't see the simple reduction... Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

One way you could approach this is to create a wrapper type for `Node` instances with a `reduce` method that Ramda can dispatch to, allowing you to summarise an entire tree of `Node` instances.

```
const node = (n) => ({
  reduce(f, z) {
    switch(n.nodeType) {
      case Node.TEXT_NODE:
        return f(z, n)
      case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
        return R.reduce(
          (_z, _n) => node(_n).reduce(f, _z),
          f(z, n),
          n.childNodes
        )
      default:
        return z // ignore other node types
    }
  }
})
```

If you're interested in collecting a list of `Text` nodes, you can now selectively add them to a list through `reduce`.

```
const isInterestingTextNode = R.both(
  R.propEq('nodeType', Node.TEXT_NODE),
  R.propSatisfies(R.complement(R.test(/^\s*$/)), 'textContent')
)

const textNodesOf = R.pipe(node, R.reduce((textNodes, node) => {
  if (isInterestingTextNode(node)) textNodes.push(node.textContent)
  return textNodes
}, []))
```

You can see an example of this in the snippet below.

```js
const node = (n) => ({
  reduce(f, z) {
    switch(n.nodeType) {
      case Node.TEXT_NODE:
        return f(z, n)
      case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
        return R.reduce(
          (_z, _n) => node(_n).reduce(f, _z),
          f(z, n),
          n.childNodes
        )
      default:
        return z // ignore other node types
    }
  }
})

const isInterestingTextNode = R.both(
  R.propEq('nodeType', Node.TEXT_NODE),
  R.propSatisfies(R.complement(R.test(/^\s*$/)), 'textContent')
)

const textNodesOf = R.pipe(node, R.reduce((textNodes, node) => {
  if (isInterestingTextNode(node)) textNodes.push(node.textContent)
  return textNodes
}, []))

console.log(textNodesOf(document.getElementById('root')))
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.22.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root">
    <div>
      <span>foo</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>bar</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```